# How to draw the branch in a graph?

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphs

[image]

I would like to know how to draw the arrow with branches above. Also, the arrow links to a node which is not shown below.

Comment: Please provide the code of what you have so far, so that others do not have to start from scratch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For only the arrow part

[image]

```
  \documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz} 
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, positioning, shapes} 
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    node distance = 1.5cm and 1cm,
    arr/.style = {draw=blue!50, ultra thick},-stealth,
    base/.style = {draw, font=\small,
        minimum height=3em, text width=5em, align=center},
    block/.style = {base, fill=#1},
    block/.default = white,
    every edge/.append style = {arr}
    ]
    \node [block] (A) {};
    \node [block, above =of A] (B) {};
    \node [block, right = of B] (C) {};
    \node [block, left = of B] (D) {};
    \coordinate[above=0.5cm of A] (aux);
    \path[arr] (A) to (B);
    \path[arr](aux) -| (C);
    \path[arr](aux) -| (D);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: would you like to upvote the answer